# What's wrong with this computation?

Tags: complex-analysis

that's an idiot question, but I have to ask. If $f: \Omega \subset \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, and $f(z(x, y)) = x² + y² +2xyi $, then $f'(z) = 2z$ by computing with the Cauchy-Riemann equation. However,  $f(z, \overline{z}) = z² -  (z - \overline{z})²/2$, hence, since $f$ differentiable, in the complex sense, $f' = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = z + \overline{z} $. What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sasha I've just put $z = x+ yi$ and $f = (x+yi)(x+yi) + 2y²$. Something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function is not analytic: You have $u = x^2+y^2$ and $v=2xy$, so

\begin{align}
u'_x = 2x & & v'_y = 2x \\
u'_y = 2y & & v'_x = 2y 
\end{align}

i.e. $u'_y \neq -v'_x$. (With $u = x^2-y^2$ you get something analytic. Note that your $u$ is not harmonic, so it can't be the real part of an analytic function.)

Comment: I saw this in a book, so I've just accepted the differentiability as it said.  So the book is wrong. Thanks